# I am getting the sign up screen whenever I open the Pokemon GO app. What's wrong?

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

Whenever I open Pokemon GO, I get the screen I would get if I had just downloaded the game. It's asking me to sign up with a google account or if I have Pokemon trainers club. There is nothing I can press other than those buttons. What's wrong and how can I fix.

Comment: I don't see this problem as one of the potential problems in the list on the other question. If this is going to be marked as a duplicate, shouldn't this problem be added to the list?

Answer (score 0):

I would get this issue myself when the connection timed out. If you signed up via Google, clicking the Google account button will sign you in again rather than create a new account. I assume the same would happen via the Trainers Club.